# Single apex message coming in red but not multiple apex messages

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery, html, css

Couple of days back , I had a problem like  i have a page message and I want the text to be in red color.

after applying some css it worked out well.But if i am showing more than one error ,then only a heading "messages" comes in red and the messages are coming in normal color.I have added the image for your reference

CSS

```
<style>
        .messageText{
            color:red;
        }
    </style>
```

and the page message is like

```
<apex:outputPanel id="errordisplayPanel" >
        <apex:outputPanel Id="errorspanel">
            <input id="isDiscountCheckPrfmd" type="hidden" name="isDiscountCheckPrfmd" value="{!isDiscountCheckPrfmd}" />
            <c:Displayerror id="errordisplay" errorList="{!lstAllError}"  />                         
            <br/>  
        </apex:outputPanel>
        <div id="focusError"></div>                    
        <apex:pageMessages id="msg2" />
    </apex:outputPanel>
```

[image: 1]]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For multiple messages , salesforce doesnot renders like a single message so the structure is different.

Use below code, for both single and multiple:

```
<style>
        .message ul,.messageText{
            color:red;
        }
    </style>
```

Possible duplicate of [Want to make page message text red](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/106171/want-to-make-page-message-text-red/106173?noredirect=1#comment146357_106173)